# Record Not Inserting After Insert of a Record From Another Object Based on Criteria

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a requirement wherein for every new `CustomB__c` inserted that has a CustomA__c's `checkbox__c` set to `true`, create a new `CustomC__c` record.

**Custom Objects:**

```
CustomA__c : Id, Name, checkbox__c, Total_CustomB__c, Grand_Total__c
CustomB__c : Id, Name, Number__c
CustomC__c : Id, Name, CustomA__c, CustomB__c, checkbox__c, Number__c
```

For this, I created an apex class, then called this class inside an apex trigger. There's no error whatsoever when I am inserting new `CustomB__c` record. But the problem is that there's no new `CustomC__c` record created at all.

**Apex Class:**

```
public class MyController {

    public static void TotalCustomB(Set<Id> ids) {

        Decimal total = 0;
        List<CustomA__c> customAqry = new List<CustomA__c>();
        List<CustomA__c> customAList = new List<CustomA__c>();

        customAqry = [SELECT Id, Name, checkbox__c, Total_CustomB__c, Grand_Total__c, (SELECT Id, Name, Number__c FROM CustomBs__r) FROM CustomA__c WHERE ID IN: ids];

        for(CustomA__c ca : customAqry) {

            if(!ca.checkbox__c) {

                for(CustomB__c cb : ca.CustomBs__r) {

                    total += cb.Number__c;

                } 

                ca.Total_CustomB__c = total;
                ca.Grand_Total__c = total;
                customAList.add(ca);

            }

            update customAList;

        }

    }    

    public static void createNewCustomC(List<CustomB__c> newCustomB) {

        Set<Id> ids2 = new Set<Id>();
        List<CustomC__c> customCList = new List<CustomC__c>();

        newCustomB = [SELECT Id, Name, CustomA__c, CustomB__c, Number__c, CustomA__r.checkbox__c FROM CustomB__c WHERE Id =: ids2];

        for(CustomB__c cb2 : newCustomB) {

            if(cb2.CustomA__r.checkbox__c == true) {
                CustomC__c c = new CustomC__c();
                c.CustomA__c = cb2.CustomA__r.Id;
                c.checkbox__c = cb2.CustomA__r.checkbox__c;
                c.CustomB__c = cb2.Id;
                c.Number__c = cb2.Number__c;
                customCList.add(c);
            }

        } 

        insert customCList;

    }

}
```

**Apex Trigger:**

```
trigger sampleTrigger on CustomB__c (after insert, after update, after delete) {

    Set<Id> Ids = new Set<Id>();

    if(Trigger.isAfter && (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate)) {
        for(CustomB__c cb : Trigger.new) {
            Ids.add(cb.CustomA__c);
        }
    }

    else if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isDelete) {
        for(CustomB__c cb : Trigger.old) {
            Ids.add(cb.CustomA__c);
        }
    }

    if(!Ids.isEmpty()) {
        MyController.TotalCustomB(Ids);
        MyController.createNewCustomC(Trigger.New);
    }

}
```

Comment: Follow the debug logs and get the dml outside of the loops

Comment: `ids2` is a set. how would you check `Id =: ids2` in createNewCustomC for loop. You should use `id IN : ids2`

Comment: @Eric I've checked the debug logs and it says this line `DEBUG|customCList()`. This indicates that there's nothing on it.

Comment: @Reshma my bad. I tried replacing the previous line with this `id IN : ids2` , but unfortunately, it's still same

Comment: You are not adding values to `ids2`. So select query return no records

Comment: @eagerlearner for `createNewCustomC` method you're passing `Trigger.New` context whereas in the class you are again overwriting the `List<CustomB__c>` i.e. Trigger.New and `ids2 set` is always blank. So actually the list will not return anything hence the loop doesn't even iterate.

Answer (score 1):

Try Below code

In the trigger you're already constructing the Ids of `CustomA__c` record so just pass the same set of Ids in the second method which will work.

**Handler Method**

```
public static void createNewCustomC(List<CustomB__c> newCustomB) {

        List<CustomC__c> customCList = new List<CustomC__c>();

        /*newCustomB = [SELECT Id, Name, CustomA__c, CustomB__c, Number__c, CustomA__r.checkbox__c FROM CustomB__c WHERE Id IN: ids2];*/

        for(CustomB__c cb2 : newCustomB) {

            if(cb2.CustomA__r.checkbox__c == true) {
                CustomC__c c = new CustomC__c();
                c.CustomA__c = cb2.CustomA__r.Id;
                c.checkbox__c = cb2.CustomA__r.checkbox__c;
                c.CustomB__c = cb2.Id;
                c.Number__c = cb2.Number__c;
                customCList.add(c);
            }

        } 
        if(!customCList.isEmpty())
             insert customCList;

    }
```

**Apex Trigger**

```
trigger sampleTrigger on CustomB__c (after insert, after update, after delete) {

Set<Id> Ids = new Set<Id>();

if(Trigger.isAfter && (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate)) {
    for(CustomB__c cb : Trigger.new) {
        Ids.add(cb.CustomA__c);
    }
}

else if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isDelete) {
    for(CustomB__c cb : Trigger.old) {
        Ids.add(cb.CustomA__c);
    }
}

if(!Ids.isEmpty()) {
    MyController.TotalCustomB(Ids);
    MyController.createNewCustomC(Trigger.New);
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added `Set<Id> ids2` as second parameter of the `createNewCustomC` method, and did this line `MyController.createNewCustomC(Trigger.New, Ids);`. However, `CustomC__c` record is not inserted.

Comment: Add a debug statement and check whether the list `newCustomB` has any record associated with `CustomA__r.checkbox__c = true`

Comment: Not sure how to check this but I added this line below the query `System.debug('newCustomB' + newCustomB);`. It returns this in the debug log `DEBUG|newCustomB()`. Am I doing right????

Comment: @RCS you are passing list of customB's to `newCustomB`. Than why again query using `ids2`

Comment: Yes, we can work on the `Trigger.New` context i didn't look the detailed code just copy pasted that.

Comment: @RCS I removed the query part, then put the Apex trigger back on its original form. However, no `CustomC__c` is inserted and every time I delete a `CustomB__c` record, I have this error `execution of AfterDelete caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object`. This error appeared when I deleted the query.

Comment: Can you please specify the steps that how're you validating whether the trigger is executing or not? And also can you provide the debug log

Comment: Ok I got why are you getting the `Attempt to de-reference null object` error at line `insert customCList`

Comment: Do you really need all the trigger context `after insert, after update, after delete` If yes then you may need to change the logic for `createNewCustomC` as it may work in case of `After Insert` and `After Update`

Comment: Yes, I really need those events. Do you mean creating another method that will handle the `CustomB__c` deletion?

Comment: Add MyController.createNewCustomC(Trigger.New); in the If condition of isAfter Update and Insert and check whether the code works for Insert and Update

Comment: I added this line `MyController.createNewCustomC(Trigger.New);` in the if condition of isAfter Update and Insert, and commented it on the lowest part of apex trigger. But it still doesn't insert a new `CustomC__c` record.

Comment: Can you please specify the steps that how're you validating whether the trigger is executing or not? And also can you provide the debug log

Comment: About that, I am validating it through this line after the for loop: `System.debug('customCList' + customCList);`. When I try to run the process, say I manually set `checkbox__c` field to true then  create a new `CustomB__c` record, I check the debug logs and always get this :  `DEBUG|customCList()`

Answer (score 1):

Modify handler class like this. `ids2` contain ids of CustomA__c object. You were querying CustomB__c object by checking its id in `ids2`. So this always retun no value as checking CustomB record id against CustomA record id. I'm not sure why you require the below commented line.

```
trigger sampleTrigger on CustomB__c (after insert, after update, after delete) {

Set<Id> Ids = new Set<Id>();

if(Trigger.isAfter && (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate)) {
    for(CustomB__c cb : Trigger.new) {
        Ids.add(cb.CustomA__c);
    }
}

else if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isDelete) {
    for(CustomB__c cb : Trigger.old) {
        Ids.add(cb.CustomA__c);
    }
}

if(!Ids.isEmpty()) {
    MyController.TotalCustomB(Ids);
    if(Trigger.isAfter && (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate)) {
         MyController.createNewCustomC(Trigger.New);
    }
}

}
```

---

```
public static void createNewCustomC(List<CustomB__c> newCustomB) {

     List<CustomC__c> customCList = new List<CustomC__c>();
     //This line of code not required.
     //newCustomB = [SELECT Id, Name, CustomA__c, CustomB__c, Number__c, CustomA__r.checkbox__c FROM CustomB__c WHERE Id IN: ids2];

     for(CustomB__c cb2 : newCustomB) {

         if(cb2.CustomA__r.checkbox__c == true) {
             CustomC__c c = new CustomC__c();
             c.CustomA__c = cb2.CustomA__r.Id;
             c.checkbox__c = cb2.CustomA__r.checkbox__c;
             c.CustomB__c = cb2.Id;
             c.Number__c = cb2.Number__c;
             customCList.add(c);
         }

     } 
     insert customCList;
}
```

Comment: I added that query for the reason that I encounter validation error stating this line `execution of AfterDelete caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object` every time I delete a `CustomB__c` record. After adding that query, error disappears and deletion goes smoothly.

Comment: I tried commenting the query, then followed your answer above. Still, no `CustomC__c` record has been inserted.

Comment: @eagerlearner Check debug statement that `newCustomB` is empty or not

Comment: @eagerlearner Exception occurs why because if its after delete `Trigger.new` will be null. You are passing and looping through trigger.new.

Comment: `newCustomB`, according to the debug statement, is empty.

Comment: @eagerlearner is newCustomB empty for after update and after insert?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51065/discussion-between-reshma-and-eagerlearner).

Comment: `newCustomB` is not empty for after update and after insert. I tried to assert, and it shows that it has some values on it.